# Multiple integrals of dirac delta

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm working on a problem where integrals of this form arise:

$$ 
  \int\limits_{x_1=-1}^1 \;\;
  \int\limits_{x_2 =-1/3} ^{1/3} \dots 
  \int\limits_{x_n =-1/(2n+1)} ^{1/(2n+1)} \delta(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_n )  
$$

where $\delta(.) $ is the Dirac delta function (ie $\int_x \delta(x)f(x) dx = f(0) $

While this is straight forward to solve for $n \leq 6$ (i.e. $2n+1=13$), I was wondering if there is a general solution for arbitrary $n$. How does one apply the constraint that $x_1 + \dotsb + x_n =0$ in this integration?

Comment: So the argument is $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$?

Comment: Sorry - to clarify, the argument is the dirac delta of $x_1 + .. + x_n$

Comment: You have for lower bounds of integration $x_n=-\frac{1}{2n+1}$. This would imply $x_1=-\frac13$, but you have $x_1=-1$ instead. This needs to be fixed for everything to be consistent.

Comment: did you make any progress - I'm very interested in the solution of this question myself!